# php mysql I need to read a record at a time until the end

Tags: php, mysql

I have read several post stack overflow and I wrote this small program. However, instead of reading a record at a time
read the same record ...
where am I wrong?

```
// ...................................... NUMBER OF RECORD
$result = mysqli_query($data->connessione,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tsynapse")  ;
if ( $result == false ) { printf ("<br/> mysqli : Error Reading FROM tsynapse; <br/>");  break ; }
echo "<br/> record totali <br/>" ;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;
echo $row[0] . "<br/>";

// ...................................... COUNTER
$k=$row[0] ;

while ( $k-- )
{
    // ...................................... READ ONE RECORD AT TIME
    $result = mysqli_query($data->connessione,"SELECT * FROM tsynapse LIMIT 1")  ;
    if ( $result == false ) { printf ("<br/> mysqli : Error Reading FROM tsynapse; <br/>");  break ; }

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      echo $row['id'] . " XXX " . $row['tag'] . " XXX " . $row['token'] . " XXX " . $row['rule']. " XXX " . $row['trans']  ;
      echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tsynapse LIMIT 1` will only ever return a single record. You need to specify which record you want, in that case; or you can remove the LIMIT clause, and use a while loop to step through all the records returned.

Comment: Just to be clear you just want to echo each row of a table from your DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify which record to retrieve, you need to specify the offset and number of record to retrieve. See [this MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
while ($k--)
{
   $result = mysqli_query ($data->connessione, "SELECT * FROM tsynapse LIMIT {$k}, 1");
   // etc.
}
```

From the code you posted, it seems that you want to retrieve all the data from `tsynapse`.
This is a better approach which simplifies your code:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($data->connessione, "SELECT * FROM tsynapse ORDER BY id DESC"); // Since it seems that you want to retrieve from last record.
$total_record_count = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result))
{
   echo $row['id'] . " XXX " . $row['tag'] . " XXX " . $row['token'] . " XXX " . $row['rule']. " XXX " . $row['trans']  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You execute the query for each iteration. So you get the same result set each time and pick the first row in there each time.

Execute the query only once *before* the iteration and then pick the rows one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform you request outside the loop and remove the `limit 1` on your query

```
// ...................................... NUMBER OF RECORD
$result = mysqli_query($data->connessione,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tsynapse")  ;
if ( $result == false ) { printf ("<br/> mysqli : Error Reading FROM tsynapse; <br/>");  break ; }
echo "<br/> record totali <br/>" ;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;
echo $row[0] . "<br/>";

// ...................................... COUNTER
$k=$row[0] ;

// ...................................... READ ONE RECORD AT TIME
        $result = mysqli_query($data->connessione,"SELECT * FROM tsynapse")  ;
        if ( $result == false ) { printf ("<br/> mysqli : Error Reading FROM tsynapse; <br/>"); }

while ( $k-- )
{     
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      if($row == null)
      {
          break;
      }
      echo $row['id'] . " XXX " . $row['tag'] . " XXX " . $row['token'] . " XXX " . $row['rule']. " XXX " . $row['trans']  ;
      echo "<br>";
    //}
}
```

Comment: i do not want read all tsynapse table and then fetch . i have a huge data base and i need to read record in tsynapse one by one.

Comment: Define huge table please

Comment: thank you for your post , i have resolved with  "SELECT * FROM tsynapse LIMIT {$k}, 1"; thank you again